# Laravel - Constant expression contains invalid operations in x:\project\app\Model.php

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm trying to validate some data with laravel, which I have implemented in the Model itself, as such:

class Collection extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [ 'id' ];

```
public $allowedDataTypes = [

'Date',
'Text',
'Number',
'Email',
'Checkbox',
'Image',
'File',

];





25    public static $rules =  array([
26
27  'fields.*.fieldName' =>  
28      [       
29          'unique' => 'Please ensure that the fields are uniquely named.',
30          'required' => 'You must specify a name for your fields.'
31      ],
32
33  'fields.*.dataType' =>
34      [
35          'required', 'You must specify a data type for your fields.',
36          'in:'.implode(',', $allowedDataTypes)
37      ]
38
39  ]);
```

However, upon submitting data, and supposedly having it go through this validation, it gives me the error seen in the title:

> Constant expression contains invalid operations in {link to
>   model}:39

I've numbered the lines of code too and I'm not sure why this specifically is happening.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: What does dd($allowedDataTypes); output? ( do it on the start of the function)

Comment: It won't even let me get that far. I'll add the declaration of it in the question

Comment: php `!=` java. it just won't compiled, ...yet. you can't create nesting array like that on class property. Instead, set them on constructor.

Comment: You cannot use expressions in declaration. `implode(',', $allowedDataTypes)`is triggering the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to use the implode function inside the class variable declaration. This is because the class variables are initiated before runtime.

If you want to use the implode function you can use a function or use the constructor.

For example:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'fields.*.fieldName' => [
            'unique' => 'Please ensure that the fields are uniquely named.',
            'required' => 'You must specify a name for your fields.'
        ],

        'fields.*.dataType' =>      [
            'required', 'You must specify a data type for your fields.',
            'in:'.implode(',', $this->allowedDataTypes)
        ]

    ];
}
```

Comment: How would I then use it though? $this->rules() in the Validator?

Comment: I will edit my answer so that if you are using the validator inside the model you showed above you can use is like `$this->rules()`.

Comment: Try making it `public static $allowedDataTypes` and change `$this->allowedDataTypes` to `self::$allowedDataTypes`

Comment: Ok that worked. Man, I hope u find a £50 note or something today. Thank you!